# Swift test unable to find Swift class property on Objective-C VC

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

I may be in compiler hell right here.

I'm implementing a Snapshot test in Swift, calling a property on an Objective-C VC, but that property is a class, written in Swift, bridged in.

In **MyViewController.h**:

```
@class TextEntryView;

@interface MyViewController: AbstractTextEntryViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) TextEntryView *textEntryView;

@end
```

In **TextEntryView.swift**:

`@objc(TextEntryView) class TextEntryView: UIView`

And in my test, I'm trying to call

`vc.textEntryView` where vc is of type `MyViewController` and I'm getting the error:

> value of type `MyViewController` has no member `textEntryView`

My bridging headers look good. **If I add an `NSString` property to the .h file above, I'm able to reference it in the test.** Also, when I <kbd>command</kbd>-click on `MyViewController` in my test, **it takes me to the `.h` file rather than the `.swift` generated version of that file** (which seems like a symptom of this problem).

I may be pushing Xcode 8 beyond its limits.

Comment: Use the generated interface button and inspect how is your `MyViewController` translated to swift and if the property is visible there.

Comment: Please show `AbstractTextEntryViewController`. Also: can you reach `vc.textEntryView` in the app target's code (not in test)?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure you `import` your app at the top of the source file for your test. For example, if your app is called MyApp, insert at the top of the test file:

```
import MyApp
```

If I leave out the `import`, I get the same behavior you are seeing. Additionally, as long as the `import` is there, you shouldn't have to bother with bridging headers for the unit test.

Comment: Can you perhaps reduce your issue to a simplified test-case and post a project? Here is the one I made, which I set up based on the description in your question, and which seems to work as it should: http://charlessoft.com/zack_shapiro/Test.zip

Comment: Perhaps the `AbstractTextEntryViewController` has something to do with it? What is this class, how is it declared, and what is its visibility?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to import to Test Target ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Since you already imported the Xcode-generated header file for your Swift code into Objective-C .m file.

Please also remove `@objc` annotation from TextEntryView class since it's a subclass of UIView thus accessible and usable in Objective-C. keeping the annotation @objc may cause a side effect.

> To be accessible and usable in Objective-C, a Swift class must be a
>   descendant of an Objective-C class or it must be marked @objc.

a simple case of "side-effect" is when a (swift) `UIViewController` subclass is marked `@objc` and used as custom subclass in storyBoard:

`instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` will instantiate a `UViewController` instead of the subclass we set in the storyBoard.
with error `Unknown class _TtC10AbcdViewController in Interface Builder file`